# How are timeouts handled in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

Say I have the following test:

```
@Test(timeout = 1)
public void test(){
  while(true){}
}
```

This simulates a test that would take a long time to return, not from sleeping, but from raw calculation time. How does the test exit? If I create a thread and try the same thing, it does not compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {//Exception 'java.lang.InterruptedException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block'
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

I can even attempt to replicate the implementation, but it still does not interrupt the thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                doTest();
            } catch (InterruptedException throwable) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void doTest() throws Throwable {
            while (true) {
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

The `java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 1 milliseconds` exception claims to be originating strait from the while loop when running the regular test.

I am confused as to how the test is 'interrupted', but I cannot do the same with a regular thread. How is this 'interrupting' feature implemented in JUnit?

Comment: A thread can only be interrupted when it is blocked by a wait(), join(), sleep() or other blocking call.  Your "thread.interrupt()" has no effect, so as you say, it has to be some other mechanism (which I don't know off the top of my head).

Comment: From the "Core Java" book:  "You can kill a thread by invoking its stop method.  That method throws a ThreadDeath error object that kills the thread.  however, the stop method is deprecated, and you should never call it in your own code."  I don't know if that's how JUnit does it.  It may use some JVM magic that most developers don't normally need to learn about.

Comment: @MarkLutton I think I found it, it uses the `getStackTrace()` method from Thread, and gets the spot where ever the code is currently at, the wraps it in an exception. Then it calls interrupt and lets the thread go on it's merry way, exit or not (skipping to the next test while potentially leaving the last one going infinitely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tells you the truth: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java